# Can we transfer ethers using a EOS smart contract

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Suppose we  want to transfer ether from our EOS smart contract. I know `atomic swaps` is not possible between ether and EOS blockchain, may be in the future but not now. Is there any other ways round to solve this problem?

I am also want to ask that if EOS can be transferred using ethereum contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no direct way for an ethereum contract to transfer EOS or vice versa.

EOS does have [functionality for different EOS blockchains to communicate](https://cryptoslate.com/comparing-the-cross-chain-communication-protocols-of-eos-cosmos-aion-and-wanchain/) but not with Ethereum blockchains.

[Bancor is working on building a "bridge" between Ethereum and EOS](https://www.ccn.com/ethereum-dapp-bancor-is-building-a-bridge-to-the-eos-network/), but that's still in development.